# Firefox is showing a error in console with google analystics cookie

Tags: angular, firebase, google-analytics

I get the error of `"Cookie “_ga” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To know more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite"` in firefox. This is on my website. I built it with angular and am using firebase analytics. Is there any way to remove it?

```
    @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    LandscapesComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    PortraitsComponent,
    ExperimentalComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp({
      apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      authDomain: "comsma-photography.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://comsma-photography.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "comsma-photography",
      storageBucket: "comsma-photography.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
      appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }),
    AngularFireStorageModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AngularFireAnalyticsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the google analytics cookies have still not set updated their cookie settings. It's not on you, but on the analytics team to fix it. Unless that happens, it would stay this way.